# What does {foo:>7f} do in Python f-strings?

Tags: python, string, f-string

In particular, this is over my head:

```
print(f"foo: {foo:>7f}, bar: {bar:>5d}")
```

I can imagine that `f` indicates float and `d` indicates integer but I don't really understand what the `>7f` and `>5d` do.

Note that I understand what

```
print(f"foo: {foo}, bar: {bar}")
```

does.

Comment: in python3.9+ this can be shortened to `f"{=foo:>7f}  {=bar:>5f}"` :P

Comment: Did you look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)?

Comment: Yes I did but couldn't understand. Even though I understand now due to the answer I still find the wording confusing for me.

Comment: @Joran I think you have the equals in the wrong place. `f"{foo=:>7f}  {bar=:>5f}"`

Comment: lol whoops yeah :P thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the resulting string from `{foo:>7f}` should at least be of width 7, meaning that if it were 4 characters/digits long, then spaces would be appended to its left.

```py
>>> foo = 1234
>>> bar = 100
>>> f"foo: {foo:>7d}, bar: {bar:>5d}"
'foo:    1234, bar:   100'
```

Note the spaces are before each number.

```
>>> f"foo: {foo:>4d}, bar: {bar:>5d}"
'foo: 1234, bar:   100'
```

Notice how the first number isn't affected because it has width of 4.